# Append "@gmail.com" in EditText after pressing any key from user in android

Tags: android

I am thinking the logic as given below

```
editTextUserName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

       }    
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

   }    
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                appendEmail(editTextUserName.getText().toString());
            }
        });    
 void appendEmail(String email){
        if( email.length()>=1){

            editTextUserName.setText("@gmail.com");
    }
}
```

This is example code not the actual code. This is throwing the stackoverflow exception.

Can anyone resolve the isssue

Comment: On which line, are you getting the exception?

Comment: `Append “@gmail.com” in EditText after pressing any key from user in android` - By doing so, you will get an **infinite loop**. `I am thinking the logic` - Your logic is **not logical** (cit.: @MrSpock, R.I.P.).

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the substring "@gmail.com" is already exists there is no need to setText again. Because when you set text to EditText it calls afterTextChange again, and then you call appendEmail and then it sets text again etc.

```
void appendEmail(String email){
      if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && email.contains("@gmail.com")){

            editTextUserName.setText(email + "@gmail.com");
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `TextWatcher` is not appropriate here (as *m vai* commented).

Do something like in your EditText tag  add `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
         editText.setText(editText.getText().toString()+"@gmail.com");  
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Won't `afterTextChanged` be called on every letter you type? This wouldn't be really helpful, because when typing `my.email`, as soon as I type `m` I would get `m@gmail.com`.

Comment: Thanks Don Chakkappan , its working but needs a little bit changes as per my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test, but I fear `afterTextChanged()` gets called after each letter you type. If this is the case, you should try other callbacks, like losing focus:

```
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        EditText edit = (EditText) v;
        String text = edit.getText().toString();
        if (!hasFocus && text.length() > 0) {
            edit.setText(text + "@gmail.com");
        }
    }
})
```